# Java method invocation conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion, method-invocation

Hello I reading about java types conversion, so I found in the book Java Language Specification made by Oracle this quote :

> Method invocation conversion is applied to each argument in a method
>   or constructor invocation and, **except in one case**, performs the same
>   conversions that assignment conversion does.

So can someone tells me what's the excepted case ?

Comment: Which version of the JLS are you referring to?

Comment: I'm reading the Second edition

Comment: JLS (Java SE 8 edition; available at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) chapter 5 "Conversions and Contexts" defines assignment contexts (in §5.2) and invokation contexts (in §5.3).  Does that help?

Comment: The answer was found by following the first link on this very statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [chapter 5 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3):

> Method invocation conversions specifically do not include the implicit narrowing of integer constants which is part of assignment conversion (§5.2). The designers of the Java programming language felt that including these implicit narrowing conversions would add additional complexity to the overloaded method matching resolution process (§15.12.2).